# paymate return url does not return post after accepting payment

Tags: payment-gateway

Payment is being successfully accepted in paymate and then when it is returning the client to my website it does not return the output parameters at all.
The paymate payment url i am using to post values : 
https://www.paymate.com/PayMate/ExpressPayment?mid=mypaymateID&amt=100&ref=123&return=http://bondiclassifieds.com/paymatereturn.php&popup=true

On the return URL I am using both POST and REQUEST to trap values passed by paymate - but I get nothing.

Their support just gave me this URL - which I have been following since day 1 : http://www.paymate.com/cms/index.php/resources/integrating-paymate/website-a-cart-integration

Anyone who faced similar problem ? I am using custom PHP code in my website and the retun URL  and understand the basics of paymate method when they talk about the Input and Output parameters.

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I have been working on this quite a while and their documentation does not actually cover how this works?

Comment: @Shane Did you figure out anything on this , I'm on same situation!

Comment: Hi Jobin, I can not remember how exactly I went about getting around this. I can not find the code either. Off memory, you need to look at this...
https://www.paymate.com/cms/help-and-support/integrating-paymate/paymate-query-api
After they get back to your site, if I remember correctly you are given an ID in the query string which you then use to query paymate for their response.